# which one these is better for performance

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I’m solving a problem and I need to optimize my code as much as possible.

I have a loop in which I need to do some calculation and I need to add an element to an array for further calculation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lightCount; i++) {
    int dis = in.nextInt();
    int dur = in.nextInt();
    double unit = distance / duration * 3.6;
    array[i] = unit;

    if (speed < unit) {
        double n = unit / (2 * speed);

        if (!((n - (int) n) == 0))
            n = n + 1;

        int tmp = (int) (unit / (2 * (int) n));

        if (tmp < answer)
            answer = tmp;
    }
}
```

Which is the best of the following situations:

1. Use `unit` or access the array directly (replacing `unit` with `array[i]`)
2. Use intermediate variables or calculate the result directly. For example, removing `n` and replacing it with it’s formula
3. Create many methods to break down code or put all the calculations in one method

Comment: `in.nextInt()` looks like you're reading from console or a file. No matter what you do, nothing will offset the performance impact of IO.

Comment: Did you run an experiment to measure which approach was faster? What were your results? If not, what problems did you encounter that stopped you from doing this?

Comment: The micro-optimizations you're talking about are going to be dwarfed (by orders of magnitude) by the overhead of reading the input.

Comment: 1, 2, and probably 3 will all be irrelevant by the time Java’s bytecode optimiser has taken a pass at your code

Comment: in fact i'm just trying to solve an algorithmic problem, and my solution is not accepted at a certain level, because there is process time out (the solution works in my computer) it might be the algorithm that I'm using, these are just questions that come to my mind ...

Comment: Having said that, 3 is not going to speed up your code. Each method call has to go on the stack. Breaking up your code into smaller methods is for readability, not performance. The performance hit of atomatizing your operations is beyond negligible in just about every scenario compared to the readability benefits. If you're really trying to squeeze every last bit of performance out of your code though, don't do 3.

Comment: Show us the problem description and more of your solution.

Comment: If you do IO in a  loop you should completely ignore computational performance. You should always be aware of these latencies when concerned about performance https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832  . Also have a performance profiling benchmark. All low level transformations you proposed are irrelevant anyway, the JVM will optimize these much better than you can.

Answer (score 0):

1. This does not matter.
2. This only matters if you call functions in your calculations and use the same expression multiple times. In this case, it does not matter.
3. This does not matter. For readability, you might want to split different functionality into different functions.

EDIT: IO is often the bottleneck. What does in.nextInt() do? Can you move it outside of the loop?

Comment: no I can't, because I wait for input from the console

Comment: If you wait for input, then it measures the time it takes to interact with the console as well. If you use this for debugging purposes (e.g. running the program loop by loop) I suggest using breakpoints in your IDE instead.